# How to get KernelID in from KernelObject?

Tags: parallelization, kernel

In a nutshell, how can I get this number:

[image]

I'm having trouble because $KernelID isn't a function and the FullForm is this crazy thing:

[image]

**Motivation:**

After you call `CloseKernels[]`, the next time you `LaunchKernels[]` the new kernels don't start from one again:

[image]

In my parallel code I'd like to have access to the index of the kernel from 1 to $KernelCount, but I'm not sure how to efficiently get that:

```
offset = ToExpression@(StringCases[ToString[Kernels[][[1]]], NumberString][[1]])
(*Out[]= 17*)
```

Comment: What if you kept a variable where you stored the output of `LaunchKernels`, and referenced the kernels by their index (1-4) in that variable? I am sure there are practical, low-level reasons why the kernels continue to increment.

Comment: Would `1 + Mod[$KernelID - 1, $KernelCount]` do what you want? I.e., `ParallelEvaluate[1 + Mod[$KernelID - 1, $KernelCount]]` always gives, e.g., on a 4-core machine, `{1,2,3,4}`?

Comment: That won't always give the same values {3, 1, 2}, {2, 3, 1}, ...

Comment: @user6014 the function I'm writing doesn't actually launch the kernels but uses ambient ones

Comment: I deleted my comment. I misunderstood what you said in the original version of the question. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the internal, undocumented function `` Parallel`Developer`KernelID `` to do this:

```
LaunchKernels[3];
Parallel`Developer`KernelID /@ Kernels[]
```

> {1, 2, 3}

Close kernels and try again:

```
CloseKernels[];
LaunchKernels[4];
Parallel`Developer`KernelID /@ Kernels[]
```

> {4, 5, 6, 7}